# How should I understand such recursive definition of rooted tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, trees

The Definition is:
***BASIS STEP***: A single vertex r is a rooted tree.
***RECURSIVE STEP***: Suppose that T<sub>1</sub> ,T<sub>2</sub> ,…,T<sub>n</sub> are disjoint rooted trees with roots
r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub> , …, r<sub>n</sub>, respectively. Then the graph formed by starting with a root r, which is not
in any of the rooted trees T<sub>1</sub>,T<sub>2</sub>,…,T<sub>n</sub>, and adding an edge from r to each of the vertices r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub> , …, r<sub>n</sub> , is also a rooted tree.

And it put a picture to illustrate some of the rooted trees formed starting with the basis step and applying the recursive step one time and two times.
[image]

I cannot get any idea to connect the definition and the illustrated picture. 
Because, according to the definition, we have only one element of the set of rooted trees when we are in basis step, that is, the rooted tree with only one vertex. And then we applied recursive step one time, we should only produce one new rooted tree to the set, which were formed like the first one in the step 1 in the illustrated picture.
Why there were four, even more, new rooted tree produced with applying recursive step only one time? Where does I misunderstand?

Comment: Do you have a source for these images? It looks like the author is showing multiple examples of step 1 and step 2. I don't believe he is saying that we get four new graphs from the base case.

Comment: @JohnDouma It is the figure 2 on the section 5.3.3 in the book "Discrete Mathematics and Its applications" written by Kenneth H. Rosen.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are choices to make in the recursive step: every integer $n$ and every choice of rooted trees $T_1,\dots,T_n$ gives a new rooted tree at that step. Even at step $1$, where the only choice of each $T_j$ is a single vertex, there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ that result in infinitely many new rooted trees at step 1 (the illustration shows $n=1,2,3,4$).

Comment: So, it means there are two dimensions to decide how a new tree to be produced. The first is to determine how many tree we should take to make up a new tree, and the second is to determine what trees they would be.